# pm2 Read Metrics Programmatically

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 to supervise a node app, and occasionally the app is hanging. I need to detect that this has happened so that pm2 can restart the app. The easiest way seems to be to create a metric with a timestamp and update it from the app every few seconds, then the supervisor will also check the value of the metric to see if it still being updated.

The problem I am having is that I am not finding any documentation on how to read the pm2/io metrics programmatically from the pm2 supervision code.

How do I read the metrics programmatically from the pm2 supervision code?

Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Still blocked on this ... Did you found a solution ?

Comment: @Ifnot No solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's late but here's the code

```
const pm2 = require('pm2')

pm2.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(2)
  }

  pm2.list((err2, processList) => {
    if (err2) {
      console.error(err2)
      process.exit(2)
    }
    
    for (eachProcess of processList) {
      console.log(eachProcess.pm2_env.axm_monitor)
    }
  })


});
```